# Asp .NET Button - OnClientClick="return function()" vs OnClientClick="function()"

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

In an asp.net user control I have a button:

```
<asp:Button ID="addButton" runat="server" Text="Add"  OnClientClick="return function()".
```

I had written jquery code to hide a control( validationsummary) present in the page inside  function().

When I wrote "return function()" it behaved as I expected and the control got hidden. While when I wrote only "function"()" the control got hidden but reappeared. What exactly is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First : the client side runs (`OnClientClick`)

Then - the server side.

**But**

The client side code *can prevent* execution of server side by return true/false.

usually we use it for validation  , before submitting to server.

Do this and your server side will ( without hacking) never work :

`OnClientClick="return false;"`