# Order of Postback Calls

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have two buttons (`ButtonA` & `ButtonB`) and a textbox (`TexboxA`) on an aspx page.

On the `TexboxA`'s blur, I call the Javascript event to click the `ButtonA` programmatically.

My question is:

1. When I'm focussing on the `TextBoxA`, then I directly clicking the `ButtonB`, which onclick event fired first? `ButtonA_Click` - since I'm losing focus of TextBoxA and triggering ButtonA click programmatically, or
   `ButtonB_Click` - because I'm directly clicking it?
2. How to prevent `ButtonB_Click` triggered before `ButtonA_Click` completely finished?

Aspx Code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxA" runat="server" onblur="ClickA();"/>

<asp:Button ID="ButtonA" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonA_Click();"/>

<asp:Button ID="ButtonB" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonB_Click();"/>
```

JS Code:

```
function ClickA(){
    document.getElementById('<%=ButtonA.ClientId%>').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your whole logic isn't very good, but if you need to do something on client side before to call the server code, you can use the method OnClientClick of your Button.

This allows also to abort the server side method click.

See here for example :

[Asp .NET Button - OnClientClick="return function()" vs OnClientClick="function()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028858/asp-net-button-onclientclick-return-function-vs-onclientclick-function)
And
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx

If the execution order of server side code matters, maybe you should ensure it on server side instead of trying to constrain it on client side.